# Vaadin - HorizontalLayout expand ratio 0 leads to 0 width

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

**Here is the UI tree with their size settings:**

HorizontalLayout (size full)

- FormLayout (size undefined, expand ratio: 0)

  - Field 1 (size undefined)
  - Field 2 (size undefined)
  - Field 3 (size undefined)
- Panel (size full, expand ratio: 1)

  - Label (width 100%, height undefined)

---

**What I want:**

Give the FormLayout the minimum space it needs, and the rest of the space should be occupied by the Panel.

---

**What happened:**

The FormLayout has 0 width (practically invisible) and the Panel takes the whole space.

If expand ratio are both 1, the form layout and panel seem to have exactly the same width.

Is what I did incorrect? How to get it so that the FormLayout keeps its size, and only the Panel will grow horizontally?

EDIT:

Main View Class:

```
private HorizontalLayout layout;

private FormLayout formLayout;
private TextField title;
private Upload upload;
private ComboBox<String> charset;
private Button btnSubmit;

private TextViewer textViewer;



public TextUploadView() {
    createTitle();      
    createUpload();
    createBtnSubmit();
    createCharset();
    formLayout = new FormLayout(title, upload, charset, btnSubmit);

    textViewer = new TextViewer();

    layout = new HorizontalLayout(formLayout, textViewer);
    layout.setSizeFull();
    layout.setExpandRatio(formLayout, 0);
    layout.setExpandRatio(textViewer, 1);
}
```

The TextViewer is the Panel with a Label in it:

```
public class TextViewer extends Panel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Label labelText;

    public TextViewer() {
        super();
        labelText = new Label();
        labelText.setWidth("100%");
        labelText.setStyleName("largeTextDisplay");

        super.setContent(labelText);
        super.setSizeFull();
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        labelText.setValue(text);
    }

}
```

I don't think the css on the label is causing any problem but it's this:

```
.mytheme .largeTextDisplay {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: normal;
}
```

Comment: please post the code you are using

Comment: I would have thought that if you set the HorizontalLayout  to size undefined, and didn't use any expand ratios, it would look how you expect.

Comment: @ChrisM indeed, I would expect the same, but I imagine he's had some issues possibly due to layout spacing or something else. However without seeing the code and some explanation why it's not working as expected it's difficult to guess.

Comment: Thanks! I added the relevant code from my UI class. I tried without expand ratios - the result is that space is divided equally between the panel and the form layout. If the window is small, the form layout doesn't get enough space. If the window is big, there's unused 
space because the form layout doesn't need that much space.

Comment: When just doing, what you describe in your initial "scenegraph", that works as expected: https://gist.github.com/christoph-frick/58d9026c96429fc5386b9941695e1c69